# PostgreSQL - Create table in schema privilege on Cloud9

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, cloud9-ide

I'm using `PostgreSQL` on `Cloude9`. I'm trying to run a `nodejs` program which creates a `schema` in a `database` and then creates some `tables` in the `schema`. Here is what I'm trying to do and the error I get:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS salesforce;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS salesforce.contact (
    id              BIGSERIAL,
    firstName       TEXT,
    lastName        TEXT,
    email           TEXT,
    mobilePhone     TEXT,
    leadsource      TEXT,
    accountid       TEXT,
    pictureURL__c   TEXT,
    preference__c   TEXT,
    size__c         TEXT,
    loyaltyid__c    TEXT,
    password__c     TEXT,
    createddate     timestamp
  );

Error initializing Postgres tables initialized
{ [Error: permission denied for schema salesforce]
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '42501',
  file: 'aclchk.c',
  line: '3371',
  routine: 'aclcheck_error' }
```

the `PostgreSQL` is running under user `postgresql`, I'm running under user `ubuntu`, but I granted all privileges on the `database` to user `ubuntu`.
I also edited the `pg_hba.conf` file to:

```
local   all             postgres                                peer
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

what am I doing wrong?
Thanks,
Nir.

Comment: Granting all privileges on the database doesn't do what you think it does. [Grant docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-grant.html).

Comment: Try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19045149/error-permission-denied-for-schema-user1-gmail-com-at-character-46

Answer (score 1, accepted):

started all from scratch and after creating a role with superuser and login options, it worked fine.