# How to grant lambda permission to create row in Aurora Postgresql database?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I have a lambda and use IAM authentication to connect to RDS Aurora postgresql 11.8. The connection part works but the I can't insert a row into a table.

I created this user in the DB and use this user to connect to db.

```
CREATE USER mydbuser WITH LOGIN; 
GRANT rds_iam TO mydbuser;
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA "test" TO mydbuser;
```

I have added the role policy for this lambda:

```
- Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - rds-db:connect 
                Resource: "arn:aws:rds-db:${self:provider.region}:${self:provider.accountId}:dbuser:*/*"
- Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - rds:*
                Resource: "arn:aws:rds:${self:provider.region}:${self:provider.accountId}:*:*"
```

when I run `insert into` and I got below error. `test` is the schema name in the database. I wonder how I can grant the lambda permission to insert row in the table under `test` schema.

```
{
  "message": "permission denied for schema test",
  "length": 97,
  "name": "QueryFailedError",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "code": "42501",
  "position": "13",
  "file": "aclchk.c",
  "line": "3522",
  "routine": "aclcheck_error",
  "query": "INSERT INTO \"test\".\"Customers\"(\"customerUuid\", ...",
  "parameters": [
    ...
  ]
}
```

Comment: Does the user have [access to the schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19045149/error-permission-denied-for-schema-user1-gmail-com-at-character-46), as well as the table(s) in the schema?

Comment: You are probably right that the user doesn't have schema permission. But I have run `GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA "test" TO mydbuser;`  and it doesn't help.