# permission denied for schema in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I already have a DB user called `api_user`.

I log in to Postgres via an admin user (`migration_user`), run the following queries (attached to the end) to create tables and schemas, and grant the schema and table permission to `api_user`.

But I get a permission denied error when logging into the DB via `api_user` and trying to access any of the tables I created.
Error I get

```
permission denied for schema retailers
LINE 1: select * from retailers.countries;
```

The query which the admin user ran to create tables and schemas.

```
SELECT current_database();
create schema retailers;
create schema gatherers;

GRANT USAGE, SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA retailers TO api_user;
GRANT USAGE, SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA gatherers TO api_user;

GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, REFERENCES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA retailers TO api_user; 
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, REFERENCES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA gatherers TO api_user; 

create table retailers.countries(ID varchar(100) primary key not null, label varchar(500) not null, iso_alpha2 varchar(2) not null, iso_alpha3 varchar(3) not null);
```

Many suggested GRANT USAGE role should solve this. But on adding that also still facing it.
Also error message states permission is missing on the schema. Not sure what permission need to be provided to give access to schema.

You can try executing the above SQL in some [playground](https://www.crunchydata.com/developers/playground). There also I am able to reproduce this. so the issue is with the way I am giving the permissions in SQL.

Checked the permissions assigned to the table `retailers.countries`
via the command

```
\z retailers.countries;
```

and I see the api_user has all relevant permissions.

```
  Schema   |   Name    | Type  |           Access privileges           | Column privileges | Policies 
-----------+-----------+-------+---------------------------------------+-------------------+----------
 retailers | countries | table | migration_user=arwdDxt/migration_user+|                   | 
           |           |       | api_user=arwdx/migration_user         |                   |
```

What permission I am missing?

Edit:
Unlike this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19045149/error-permission-denied-for-schema-user1-gmail-com-at-character-46) I have granted all the schema related permission also to the `api_user` in the lines `GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, REFERENCES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA retailers TO api_user;` . Still facing the issue.

Comment: The issue was with the permission to connect to the database was missing from user.

Comment: Running this SQL along with `GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE database_name TO api_user;`